# How to warp image

Tags: jquery, html, css, kineticjs

I am working a project where we need to warp image

Basically, I want to take this image:

[image]

And turn it into this:

[image]

**Please note :** text also warped.

I honestly have no clue how to go about it so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is demo what exactly i want [IMAGELINK](http://www.vistaprint.in/vp/ns/easypath/studio.aspx?ref=2&page=1&doc_id=2775999457&pf_id=A0Y&combo_id=579404&ssc=1&ink_pad_color=1&orig_combo1=342419.120.1.195042%7C195042%7C137%7C0%7C%7C-1&orig_combo2=342418.142.1.195042%7C195042%7C137%7C0%7C%7C-1&upimg1=859205267&image_list=-859205267&click=2&back_url=http://www.vistaprint.in/gallery/IHEAAAABAAAAAAA=/mugs.aspx?xnav=Mugs_TsrButton&upimg1=859205267&image_list=-859205267&combo1=342419.120.1.195042%7C-859205267%7C137%7C0%7C%7C-1&combo2=342418.142.1.195042%7C195042%7C137%7C0%7C%7C-1&uei=449204&ag=true)

please upload above image on link and see the output.

Comment: What have you already tried? No-one will write it for you...

Comment: @BenM : OP says `I honestly have no clue` ...that gives a clue ;)

Comment: Then it's off-topic for Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: A google search with 'css wrapping' will help you get 'clues'

Comment: @BenM :  ohh come on....helping an honest person is not off topic...seriously even i don't know what keyword to type in Google for this..... just tell him the **keywords** , that would be a start for him!! :)

Comment: Wait... You want to turn it into an image you've already made? Can't you just use that image?

Comment: @BeatAlex : gud point...but what if images are coming dynamically on page....user uploaded kind of snaps???

Comment: Ahh gotcha! And he wants to assign them a class to get them all like that?

Comment: @BeatAlex : and hence u solved the big bang theory!! :D

Comment: i have turn it using photoshop i want trun it run time.

Comment: My mother will be so proud.

Comment: @BeatAlex : try NASA rather than SO.. :p

Comment: @user3414955 : mate did u got anything googling??

Comment: nothing much trying kinetic js

Comment: http://codeslashslashcomment.com/2012/12/12/dynamic-image-distortion-html5-canvas/

Comment: [CSS3 perspective properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp) and [CSS3 skew](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Your question has been closed, but here is a Fiddle showing how to cut your image into 1-pixel-wide slices and then warp that image by vertically offsetting those vertical slices:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6etMC/

Answer (score 7):

well that s not easy for the text i will use this to save time [css warp](http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/)
or use html5 have a look at [Pure CSS Coke Can](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/)

you can find  the same [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LTXXp/2)  here note that you have to scroll left or right to see it in action

```
    #coke
    {
        width: 510px;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    img
    {
        border: 0;
        margin-left: -172px;
    }

    a
    {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 19px;
        width: 194px;
    }

    a:hover img
    {
        background-image: url('coke-title.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 15px 100px;
    }

    div div
    {
        background-image: url('coke-scroll.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 0;
        padding-left: 300px;
        width: 660px;
    }

    p
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
        height: 336px;
        background-image: url('http://s21.postimg.org/fd9h4yy7r/coke_label.jpg');
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        width: 1px;
    }

    #x1 {background-position: 5px 30px;}
    #x2 {background-position: 0px 30px;}
    #x3 {background-position: -3px 30px;}
    #x4 {background-position: -6px 30px;}
    #x5 {background-position: -8px 30px;}
    #x6 {background-position: -10px 30px;}
    #x7 {background-position: -12px 30px;}
    #x8 {background-position: -14px 30px;}
    #x9 {background-position: -15px 30px;}
    #x10 {background-position: -16px 30px;}
    #x11 {background-position: -17px 30px;}
    #x12 {background-position: -18px 30px;}
    #x13 {background-position: -19px 30px;}
    #x14 {background-position: -20px 30px;}
    #x15 {background-position: -21px 30px;}
    #x16 {background-position: -22px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x17 {background-position: -23px 30px;}
    #x18 {background-position: -24px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x19 {background-position: -25px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x20 {background-position: -26px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x21 {background-position: -27px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x22 {background-position: -28px 30px; width: 3px;}
    #x23 {background-position: -29px 30px; width: 3px;}
    #x24 {background-position: -30px 30px; width: 4px;}
    #x25 {background-position: -31px 30px; width: 5px;}
    #x26 {background-position: -32px 30px; width: 7px;}
    #x27 {background-position: -33px 30px; width: 12px;}
    #x28 {background-position: -34px 30px; width: 55px;}
    #x29 {background-position: -35px 30px; width: 11px;}
    #x30 {background-position: -36px 30px; width: 6px;}
    #x31 {background-position: -37px 30px; width: 5px;}
    #x32 {background-position: -38px 30px; width: 4px;}
    #x33 {background-position: -39px 30px; width: 3px;}
    #x34 {background-position: -40px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x35 {background-position: -41px 30px; width: 3px;}
    #x36 {background-position: -42px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x37 {background-position: -43px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x38 {background-position: -44px 30px;}
    #x39 {background-position: -45px 30px; width: 2px;}
    #x40 {background-position: -46px 30px;}
    #x41 {background-position: -47px 30px;}
    #x42 {background-position: -48px 30px;}
    #x43 {background-position: -49px 30px;}
    #x44 {background-position: -50px 30px;}
    #x45 {background-position: -51px 30px;}
    #x46 {background-position: -52px 30px;}
    #x47 {background-position: -53px 30px;}
    #x48 {background-position: -54px 30px;}
    #x49 {background-position: -56px 30px;}
    #x50 {background-position: -58px 30px;}
    #x51 {background-position: -60px 30px;}
    #x52 {background-position: -62px 30px;}
    #x53 {background-position: -65px 30px;}
    #x54 {background-position: -68px 30px;}
    #x55 {background-position: -74px 30px;}
```

many thanks to  **Bill Criswell** for his comment `I'd drink this:` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LTXXp/2)

Comment: I'd drink this: http://jsfiddle.net/LTXXp/2/

Comment: ok i add it to the post

Comment: +1 to you for attracting @BillCriswell's cool Fiddle.

Comment: I only replaced one line of code from what kougiland posted haha. I think it's a cool effect, not exactly what OP was going for though, sadly.

Comment: but that line was the correct image, and since i was using a different image i think it is fair to add your image as it is on the current demo.

Comment: i just realised, coke won't work on chrome on MAC!!