# Paradoxical effect for HTML <div>s using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I am stuck here. Please help.
I want to make the following through css.[image: four layers]

But when I use CSS positioning, I am getting this output
[image]

The fourth(GREEN) layer should go under first layer(BLUE) which is not happening. 
This is the code I used.

HTML:

```
<div class="box1">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="box3">
</div>
<div class="box4">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
height:100px;
width:100px; 
border:solid 1px;
}

.box1{
position:relative;
left:500px;
background-color:#00d8ff;
}

.box2{
position:relative;
left:570px;
top:-30px;
background-color:#f6ff00;
}

.box3{
position:relative;
left:500px;
top:-60px;
background-color:#ff69fa;
}

.box4{
position:relative;
left:430px;
top:-230px;
background-color:#24ff00;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkubs/

Even I tried to use Z-index. But no use. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very tricky scenario. I think you need to split the box in two sections and then you need to apply the z-index.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352649/css-z-index-paradox-flower

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## [WORKING DEMO :before](http://jsfiddle.net/h7xbA/3/)

**senario**:

Using only one pseudo-element `:before` you just need to set `border-top` and `border-right` then give it an absolute position on the bottom left of `div2`

With the same HTML code as OP all you need is a [Pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `:before` or `:after`  combine witn [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). To make it easy i put numbers in your HTML.

Note: you habe to set position relative to the element with the `pseudo`, the set the top border and the [**right border**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) you can skeep that using [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) too see [WORKING DEMO WITH BOX-SHADOW](http://jsfiddle.net/h7xbA/4/).

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">1
</div>
<div class="box2">2
</div>
<div class="box3">3
</div>
<div class="box4">4
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
height:100px;
width:100px; 
border:solid 1px;
}

.box1{
position:relative;
left:500px;
background-color:#00d8ff;
z-index:3;
}

.box2{
position:relative;
left:570px;
top:-30px;
background-color:#f6ff00;
z-index: 3;
}
.box2:before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: -2px;
left: -2px;
width: 32px;
height: 30px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
z-index: 14;
background-color: #ff69fa;
}
.box3{
position:relative;
left:500px;
top:-60px;
background-color:#ff69fa;
z-index:1;    
}

.box4{
position:relative;
left:430px;
top:-230px;
background-color:#24ff00;
z-index:2;
}
```

[image]

## [WORKING DEMO WITH BOX-SHADOW](http://jsfiddle.net/h7xbA/4/)

Here you just need to change the `width` and `height` of `.box2`.

**senario**:

you choose one `div` in my case `div2` you don't set the background-color then reset the the borders `border:none;` .

Since you have set `div` width, height and position relative you can now set `:before` and 'after' width a 100% width and 50% height, one on the top and the other on the bottom, then for `:before` set `border-top` and for `:after` set  `border-bottom`.

Now set for both of then `border-left` and `border-right`.

```
div{
height:100px;
width:100px; 
border:solid 1px;
position:relative;
}

.box1{
left:500px;
background-color:#00d8ff;
z-index:3;
}

.box2{
left:570px;
top:-30px;
border:none;
}
.box2:before,.box2:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;   
background-color:#f6ff00;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
left: 0;
border-left:1px solid black;
border-right:1px solid black;
}
.box2:before{
top: 0;
z-index: 3;
border-top:1px solid black;
}
.box2:after{
bottom: 0;
z-index: 0;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
.box3{
left:500px;
top:-60px;
background-color:#ff69fa;
z-index:1;    
}

.box4{
left:430px;
top:-230px;
background-color:#24ff00;
z-index:2;
}
```

## [WORKING DEMO :BEFORE :AFTER FLEXIBLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/h7xbA/6/)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you can do that with normal way, a little hack may be help.

What i do is to add another box right under `.box1` with `z-index` above of all, and with size 50% of the parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box1-fake"></div>
</div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
<div class="box4"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box1-fake{
    background-color:#00d8ff;
    position:absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Yours is simple and effective. But one problem.
When I add text to div box1 It is not visible because of z-index of fake div. Can you give any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `clip` on a pseudo element after the first box to get this working:

```
.box1:after {
    content: "";
    border:solid 1px;
    background: #00d8ff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    clip: rect(76px 32px 102px -1px);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rkubs/1/)**

[image]

For more information about the css clip property see [this mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

It also has [cross browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip#Browser_Compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

Split the left box in two sections, upper and lower section, and assign z-indexes accordingly.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AshleyMedway This is not a comment at all, it is a perfectly valid answer, that also works (there is just no code given, but that is not required by SO)

Comment: @Mecki Saying try something, with no example, explanation or linked resource is not an answer.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Samples and explanations have never been required on SO. What Mukesh posted is a perfectly working solution that also solves the problem. And it plays no role if he uses the phrase "Try" or not; but if you have such a huge problem with that word, let me remove it for you.

Answer (score 2):

How about somethign like this:

```
<div class="box2">
<div class="box-top"></div> 
<div class="box-bot"></div>
</div>
```

## css ##

```
.box2 {
position: relative;
left: 570px;
top: -30px;
border: none;
}

.box-top {
z-index: 200;
position: relative;
border-bottom: none;
height: 50%;
background-color: #f6ff00;
}

.box-bot{
z-index: 200;
/* position: relative; */
left: 570px;
border-top: none;
height: 50%;
background-color: #f6ff00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8fXP/30/